# how can i get every 4th element of the array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

My question is i have an `NSMutableArray` with the name of `latLongArray` which contains object if the array count is greater than 4.

I want to add every 4th object in another Array with name  elementArray and if less than 4 want to add all object in elementArray and than print all the the data in NSLog

can any body help me in this i am new to iPhone development.
here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    placeDC *placedc;
    placedc  = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    if ([txtFrom isFirstResponder]) {

        txtFrom.text=cellText;

        NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
        originlat=placedc.latitude;
        originlng=placedc.longitude;
        NSLog(@"%@",placedc.countryFullName);
    }
    else
{
    txtTo.text=cellText;
    destinationLat=placedc.latitude;
    DestinationLng=placedc.longitude;
    DBHandler *db=[[DBHandler alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@",placedc.countryFullName);
    latLongArray=[db googlePlaces:originlat :originlng :destinationLat :DestinationLng];
    if ([latLongArray count]>4) {
        for (int i =0; i<=[latLongArray count]; i=i+4) {

        }
        NSLog(@"%d",[elentArray count]);
           }
   }

    myTableView.hidden=YES;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

Comment: not working element array count 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change :

```
NSMutableArray *newArrayOfFourthElement = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int j = 3;
if ([latLongArray count]>4) 
{
   for (int i =0; i <= [latLongArray count]; i=i+4)
   {
      if (j < [latLongArray count])
      {
            [newArrayOfFourthElement addObject:[latLongArray objectAtIndex:j]]; // This line will add all the forth element(i.e. 4,8,12....) from your latLongArray to newArrayOfFourthElement array.
      }
      j = j + 4;
   }
}
else
{
   elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:latLongArray];
}

NSLog("New array is %@",newArrayOfFourthElement);
NSLog("elementArray is %@",elementArray);
```

Comment: not working element array cout 0

Comment: @Da_smokes Thanks :)
Saleem Last nslog is giving you 0?

Comment: yes @Rushi the ns log give me 0 and thaks for quick rply

Comment: @Saleem in your code where are you declaring elentArray array??

Comment: Ohh So the problem is you need to allow elementArray before you copy anything in to it. Just allow it before your for loop and check. See i edited my code.

Comment: thanks @Rushi its working now how can i extract data from newArrayOfFourthElement Array

Comment: You can directly use objectAtIndex property of NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Rushi upvote the question and also see this

Comment: @Rushi see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412017/nsinvalidargumentexception-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x84965a0

Comment: @Rushi -> check before copy paste

Comment: can you please explain me what the mean of this line in your code     for (int i =0; i <= [latLongArray count]; i=i+4) {
   }

Comment: hmm...now its working but you can make it more compact

Comment: @Rushi -> you are working in training institute?

Comment: now i removed my down vote..

Comment: The comments are not a good place for long discussions, please move to the chat if you want to continue!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) arrayExample{
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (_longArray.count > 4) {
        int lastObjectIndex = _longArray.count -1;
        int nextIndexToAd = 3;
        while (nextIndexToAd <= lastObjectIndex) {
            [newArray addObject:[_longArray objectAtIndex:nextIndexToAd]];
            nextIndexToAd += 4;
        }
    }
    else{
        newArray = [_longArray mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to add fourth element

```
NSMutableArray *elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if ([latLongArray count]>4)
{
    //add 4th element mean object at index 3
    [elementArray addObject:[latLongArray objectAtIndex:3]];
}
else{
    elementArray=[latLongArray mutableCopy];
}
NSLog(@"elentArray array >> %@  and count = %d",elentArray,[elentArray count]);
```

And if you want to add every fourth element

```
NSMutableArray *latLongArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9", nil];
    NSMutableArray *elementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([latLongArray count]<4)
    {
        elementArray=[latLongArray mutableCopy];
    }
    else{
        do {
            [elementArray addObject:[latLongArray objectAtIndex:3]];
            [latLongArray removeObjectsInRange:(NSRange){0, 4}];
        } while ([latLongArray count]>4);

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",elementArray);
```

Comment: i want to add every 4th element

Comment: so it will add 4th element. what is the problem with this?

Comment: thanks @Saleem if you get any problem then ask :)

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412017/nsinvalidargumentexception-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x84965a0

Comment: and @Rushi your answer  will crash...check

Comment: i did not have any deal with him, first he accept my answer....then he said to up vote... i though he need 15 point so that he can able to up-voting..